# Charts in HTML5 for android?

Tags: android, html, canvas, charts

I want to show some year wise analysis using different type of charts in my android mobile application.Can anyone please provide some good links which help me in implementing these things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link.It really has some good examples.

http://www.highcharts.com/

Hope it helps you in getting your desired form.

Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's really a nice link seems to be helpful i'll go through it.

Comment: This link is really good it has almost all types of charts i want almost solved thnaks @android Phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.[Chart and Graph Library for Android](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html).
This is an example code:

```
GraphView graphView = new GraphView(
  this // context
  , new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(2.5, 3.0d) // another frequency
    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(5, 3.0d)
  } // data
  , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
  , null // dynamic labels
  , null // dynamic labels
);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
layout.addView(graphView);
```

For creating charts using JScript and HTML see this [tutorial](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-charts-the-html5-and-javascript-way/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am not using android native code i want it using html.

Comment: See the html and js tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

One of the charting solutions for Android is AChartEngine. You can find information on their [website](http://www.achartengine.org/) and on their development [website](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/).

However, please note that you can do even offline charts and also note that this is not done using HTML5.